# return before finally in java

Tags: java

In this case, does "myMethod()" get executed before or after "doSomething()"?

```
public class Foo {
    public void fooMethod() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.barMethod().myMethod();
    }
}

public class Bar {
    public SomeClass barMethod() {
        try {
            return new SomeClass();
        } finally {
            doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check that yourself by adding `System.out.println` statements to your methods!?

Comment: or there is even a better way: Why don't you check it by debugging your code and seeing the call stack ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`myMethod()` executes *after* `doSomething` because `doSomething` is executed *before* `barMethod` returns its value to the caller.

The value gets calculated and prepared to be returned, then the `finally` block executes in its entirety, and only then the caller gets to proceed; this is when `myMethod` gets called.

Answer (score 0):

doSomething() before myMethod()

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] a){
       new Foo().fooMethod();
   }

public static class Foo {

    public void fooMethod(){
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.barMethod().parseInt("sc");
    }

}

public static class Bar {

    public Integer barMethod(){
        try {
            return new Integer(100);
        } finally {
            doSomething();
        }
    }

    private void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("doSomething");
    }

}
}
```

it crashes after displaying "doSomething"